# debugger; in the Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Open a page in Chrome, enter the JavaScript console, and type `debugger;`. Immediately we hit a breakpoint at line 2 of the following code:

```
with ((window && window.console && window.console._commandLineAPI) || {}) {
debugger;
}
```

Can anyone make sense of this? Why the `with` statement? Why the breakpoint on `debugger;`?

Comment: I can only assume this is part of the functionality of the chrome debugger. They are wrapping the statements you execute into the command line `with` an isolated scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know what [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) is?

"Invokes any available debugging functionality. If no debugging functionality is available, this statement has no effect."

The code is basically saying if there is a console available with this browser and it has the feature "_commandLineAPI", start up the debugger.

The "[with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)" statement basically is a catch all way to make sure there is not an error. In reality they should have just used an if.

Comment: Yes, I constantly use the debugger. I don't see how your answer clarifies the `with` statement or the breakpoint.

Comment: I answered the question....why the breakpoint on the debugger statement. Added a line for with explanation. In reality, do not do this, it is bad practice to use with.

Comment: `with` ensures that the console object is in scope. An empty object is passed in scope as the fallback.

Answer (score -2):

Debug javascript Chrome doesn't need 'debugger' command.
Ctrl+Shift+J to Opens Developer Tools.
In the 'Sources' you can locate your js file or javascript in html.
Then click on line number to make a breakpoint on the left side.
Breakpoint will be triggered when it's executed.
You were in the command console that Chrome will try to excute any command line you input.